# Size of a process/thread in Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, kernel

What is the size of a process/thread in Linux? When a process/thread is created, along with `task_struct` and other data structure inside it, is there anything else?

Is the stack of a process/thread allocated upon process/thread initialization (fixed size)? Or is it allocated when necessary (like virtual memory)?

How can I know what size a standard process/thread when it is created in memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a large block of memory (> pagesize = 4096 bytes) is first allocated on Linux it uses special "null" memory pages in the pagetable that aren't backed by anything, so when a thread is started it will allocate ~1 MB of these zero pages for a thread stack.  As the stack grows the pages are then converted into real memory backed pages.  Because of this "null" page backing it is generally okay to have liberally large stacks.

Threads and processes are both created with the same underlying syscall called **clone(2)**.  It has lots of options and does lots of stuff.  see `man clone` for a detailed explanation.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone

Large blocks of memory are allocated with an anonymous **mmap(2)** call.

You may also be interested in doing a web search for "linux overcommit bit"

(If you want to refine your question, I can be more specific.)

Comment: Thanks. So, each thread is reserved with 1MB for its stack size. However, you said that the memory of a thread is only allocated when it is really needed, which means the physical memory doesn't lose another physical 1MB until the thread writes something to memory, does it? If this is the case, consider that my kernel is 50 MB (for example) and my memory is 70MB, can I still allocate more than 20 threads? Or the kernel actually reserves 1MB in physical memory?

Comment: Also, when I type `uname -a`, my stack size limit is 8192 kb. Is this the upper limit per process/thread?

Comment: Isn't also each process on Linux getting its own bunch of page tables that can grow to several MBs?

Comment: The stack is initially formed with null pages and not using physical memory.  Reads will return 0, writes will cause a page fault causing them to become backed with real memory.  Say you push the first item on the stack, only the first page will be backed using a total of 4096 bytes of physical memory.  Once you push more than 4096 bytes, page 2 will be backed by physical memory - and so on.  So you can see the stack only uses approximately the amount of physical memory it needs (within a granularity of 4096 bytes).

Comment: How about `kthread`? Is each thread allocated with a fixed stack size listed in `uname -r` immediately?

Comment: kthreads are for use inside the kernal (by device drivers for example) and are not accessible from userland processes.  I don't know much about them sorry.  I don't know if the clone syscall calls start_kthread to make a new process or thread, or if kthread is a seperate kernel facility.

Answer (score 1):

What Andrew said it true, but it doesn't mean your thread/process doesn't "use memory" from the moment it's created. The space reserved for stacks always consumes *virtual address space* in your process, which means with large thread stacks you'll quickly run out of addresses on 32-bit machines (just about 300 threads with default thread-stack-size on glibc will exhaust virtual address space). Also, stacks contribute to *commit charge*, which determines the total amount of memory that can be allocated when overcommit is disabled.

Linux by default pre-commits 128k for the main thread's stack, and allows more to be obtained automatically if commit charge has not been exhausted. Thread stacks are allocated entirely by userspace (glibc/NPTL, on most Linux systems) and cannot grow beyond their initial size. Depending on the version and system settings, glibc/NPTL usually defaults to allocating somewhere between 2 MB and 10 MB per thread.

Comment: Thanks. What's about the stack size in kbytes shown by `uname -a`? 

In the end, the size of a thread is the size of `thread_info struct` + `kernel stack (8KB)` + `thread stack (user stack, 2MB~10MB)`?

Comment: This is a good point about 32-bit virtual address space running out.  I live in 64 bit land where this is not an issue.